# Is the "SQL Server 2005 Database Project" the thing I'm looking for in this use case?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, portability

Please refer to my previous question here:
[Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710648/im-trying-to-grasp-the-concept-of-creating-a-program-that-uses-a-ms-sql-database)

Will this project type be useful for installing the necesary database on a servers machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what you want.  That project type is for creating [SQL Server CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28VS.80%29.aspx) objects.

You need to actually install [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/), the product, or [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), on the server machine.

Edit: Actually this might not be entirely correct under all circumstances.  If you have the Database Edition of Visual Studio then you have different SQL Server projects which are intended for deploying and upgrading databases.  But they still won't install SQL Server for you - you (or your customer) will have to do that separately.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help man. :) My next question is, what type of project do I have to make to declare all the tables that I'll need, test it out locally on my machine and then have a user easily install the database on their server machine - granted they have to have MS SQL installed prior.